# Solana Test Validator -- dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib

Tags: macos, openssl, macos-catalina, solana

### Platform

MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

### Problem

Running `solana-test-validator` throws an error regarding openssl.

```
$ solana-test-validator

>> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
>> Reason: image not found
```

### Solution

Resolved with Homebrew

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved with Homebrew

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```